# Huffman algorithm for decompress an already compressed bytes

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a byte array in the database which has been compressed using the Huffman algorithm in *Delphi*. Now I need to decompress it in `SSIS` (*SQL Server Integration Services*).

I need some `C#/.NET` code, or a tool to decrypt the bytes into a file, based on the Huffman algorithm. There are a few tools in the market that unpack a compressed file, but I don't have the file with full header for `LHA` compression. I need a way to somehow  convert a series of bytes to a decompressed file, and then save it to a file.

Comment: Huffman encodes data based on frequencies found in the original data. If you don't have the header that gives you the frequency/mapping information, you won't be able to decode it (at least not without applying some cryptographic techniques). If you do have the frequency/mapping information, please be more specific about what you have, the exact format, what you have tried so far, what happened when you tried that, and how that was different from what you wanted to happen. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

With Huffman compression, each character in your input file will map to a sequence of bits. If you have access to the Delphi source code, you can try to figure out how the frequency and character mapping information was done. Is the mapping included in the compressed file? You will need that mapping in order to write the code to decompress the file.